# Most pins in a chess game

Tags: famous-games, pins

I've looked at a few chess games on ChessBase that have a lot of pins, and I am wondering, what is the most number of pins that has occurred in a game, and what is the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most pins in a real game position that I know is **3** from an extremely famous game nicknamed "On Pins And Needles" by [chessgames.com.](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1761734) Agadmator covered in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ21bBhhchM) a few years ago.

```
[Title "Geoff Chandler-Richard Kynoch, Edinburgh Club Championship, Scotland, 1981"]
[FEN ""]
[startply "53"]

1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 3. e5 Bf5 4. Nc3 e6 5. g4 Bg6 6. Nge2 c5 7. Be3 Nc6 8. dxc5 Nxe5 9. Nd4 Rc8 10. Bb5+ Nc6 11. Qe2 Nf612. O-O-O Be7 13. h4 h5 14. f3 Nd7 15. gxh5 Rxh5 16. Rhg1 Nxd4 17. Bxd4 Qc7 18. Rxg6 fxg6 19. Qxe6 Rf5 20. Nxd5 Qd8 21. Qxg6+ Rf7 22. Re1 Kf8 23. Qh7 Ke8 24. Qg8+ Rf8 25. Qxg7 Rf7 26. Qg8+ Rf8 27. Nf6#
```

Comment: And that is why, ladies and gentleman, you should castle :)